# React Native : Not Fetched Firebase Storage Image

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob, react-native-image

i am using **react-native-image-cache-hoc** & **Blob**

```
const CacheableImage = imageCacheHoc(Image, {
  fileHostWhitelist: ['firebasestorage.googleapis.com']
});
```

and  render

```
<CacheableImage style={styles.image} source={{ uri: this.props.uri }} permanent={false} />
```

**this.props.uri  :**

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tura-113e0.appspot.com/o/userImages%2Fa@a.com%2Fimages%2FG%C3%B6khan%20Geyik?alt=media&token=54864e18-b9ce-42f3-84ae

*** Then Error : 
 props.source.uri should be a web accessible url with a valid protocol and host. NOTE: Default valid protocol is https, default valid hosts are *.***

[image: error screen]

Could you help me, please ? 
Thank you.

Comment: your image url returns a 404. that might be the issue.

Comment: Hello, no i deleted my app name in url.  So you can not open it. But it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem**.  I changed 'react-native-cacheable-image' to Fast Image 'react-native-fast-image.

If you want to use it you can read: 
https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image

**And i used this code then problem solved**

```
<FastImage source={{  uri: this.props.uri }} />
```

Thank You